# Sed command ran in script removes wrong line from file

Tags: shell, sed

I made a script that cleans up a config file.
Keeping it as short as possible, let's say those are contents of the config file:

```
1  "aa"
2  "bb"
3  "cc"
4  #
5  {
6  aa
7  name1
8  }
9  {
10 bb
11 name2
12 }
13 {
14 cc
15 name3
16 }
```

File has 2 sections, here divided by hash.
Cleanup starts once you provide a name. So I read the file, find e.g. 'name1', read 1 line above it, get the associated 'aa'.
Then I remove quoted "aa" with sed (in-place) using its line number (here: 1), I re-read the file to get proper line number of 'name1' (now: 6), because it has obviously shifted by one:

```
1  "bb"
2  "cc"
3  #
4  {
5  aa
6  name1
7  }
8  {
9  bb
10 name2
11 }
12 {
13 cc
14 name3
15 }
```

I create a variable (i) that marks beginning of section ((line number - 2) = 4), I print out an information what will be deleted:
`echo -e "INFO: removing lines:\n $(sed -n $i,'+3p' $file) \n"`
Output shows what will be removed:

```
{
aa
name1
}
```

but once the deletion is executed with:
`sed -i "$i",'+3d' $file`

The actual file looks like this:

```
1  "bb"
2  "cc"
3  }
4  {
5  bb
6  name2
7  }
8  {
9  cc
10 name3
11 }
```

Instead of deleting lines 4,5,6,7 it removed 3,4,5,6. I can't quite wrap my head around that, especially that when I commented out the deletion and performed it manually from the shell, everything was working fine.

Sure, I could delete the contents of the file starting from bottom or implement some other workaround, but I'm very curious what actually happened here and is this by design, to prevent such things from happening in the future.

---

Here's the relevant script part: (some things were added to aid in debugging, I didn't remove them so it should be easier to spot what is going on).

```
#!/bin/bash

function multipath {
 
if [[ `grep -Fn "$sharename" "$mpfile" |grep alias |awk '{print $1}' |wc -l` -ne 0 ]]
then
  for i in `grep -Fn "$sharename" "$mpfile" |grep alias |awk '{print $1}' |cut -d: -f1 |head -n1`
  do
    linenumber=$i
      prewwid=$(($i-1))
 
      echo "linenumber = $linenumber"
      echo "prewwid = $prewwid"
      read -p "Press enter to continue - before 1st loop"
 
      wwid=$(sed -n "$prewwid"'p' $mpfile |awk '{print $2}')
      echo "wwid: $wwid"
      thatline=$(grep -Fn $wwid $mpfile |grep '"' |awk '{print $1}' |cut -d: -f1)
      
      echo -e "INFO: removing line: $(sed -n $thatline'p' $mpfile) \n"
      sed -i -e "$thatline"'d' $mpfile
 
      read -p "Press enter to continue - before loop 2"
 
      if [[ $thatline -ge 1 ]]
      then
        i=`grep -Fn "$sharename" "$mpfile" |grep alias |awk '{print $1}' |cut -d: -f1 |head -n1`
        echo "new _i_ variable $i"
        echo $(sed -n "$i"'p' $mpfile)
      fi
      
      i=$(($i-2))
      echo "i value = $i"
      echo "i row: $(sed -n "$i"'p' $mpfile)"
      
      j=$(($i+3))
      echo "j value = $j"
      echo "j row: $(sed -n "$j"'p' $mpfile)"
 
      echo "removing lines $i through $j"
      read -p "before second removal"
      echo -e "INFO: removing lines:\n $(sed -n $i,'+3p' $mpfile) \n"
      sed -i -e "$i",'+3d' $mpfile
 
      read -p "Press enter to continue - after loop 2 - recurrence"
  done
 
multipath
 
else
        echo "nothing to do here"
        break
fi
}

mpfile=/path/to/file
read sharename
multipath
```

And here's a sample file:

```
defaults {
        find_multipaths yes
        user_friendly_names yes
}
 
devices {
    device {
#......
   }
}
 
blacklist {
}
 
blacklist_exceptions {
        wwid "aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f64"
        wwid "aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f65"
        wwid "aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f68"
        wwid "aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f69"
        wwid "aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c566c"
        wwid "aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f6b"
        wwid "aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c5675"
        wwid "aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c5676"
        wwid "aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f6c"
}
 
multipaths {
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f64
        alias   SOME_BOOT_lun.0
        }
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f65
        alias   SOME_u00_lun.1
        }
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f6c
        alias   SOME_u01_lun.2
        }
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f68
        alias   SOME_XYZ_REP_lun.111
        }
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f6b
        alias   SOME_XYZ_REP_lun.112
        }
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff000506d2b4c7357574f69
        alias   SOME_DEF_REP_a_lun.110
        }
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c566c
        alias   SOME_DEF_REP_a_lun.120
        }
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c5675
        alias   SOME_GHJ_REP_lun.131
        }
        multipath {
        wwid    aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c5676
        alias   SOME_GHJ_REP_a_lun.130
        }
```

===========================

Comment: It looks like there is a comma missing in `sed -i "$i'+3d'`, and mismatched quotes.  Copy & paste error?  Or root of the problem?

Comment: Assuming you are trying to use string concatenation to construct your sed script, it appears your fix is `sed -i "$i"',+3d' "$file"` assuming `$i` has the starting line number and `$file` has the name of the file.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - my bad, typo during the post creation - also the single quote was missing, I've just confirmed that the entry in the script is okay, so it's not the case.

Comment: I can't replicate. Are you sure `$i` is 4 when you the delete command runs?

Comment: @jhnc - I'll attach part of the script (full function that's supposed to do the thing) along with a sample file.

Comment: not sure why you made the main body into a function but have it using global vars instead of accepting parameters. . .

Comment: Is this the original format of the config file? If not, post it in your question. There may be a better solution.

Comment: what is `-DEF` ? You might want to use `j` and `k` rather than `i` and `j`. `i` is the `for` variable.

Comment: @MarkReed - this is just a part of a bigger script, and it's been wrapped because it's called multiple times. It may not be the most efficient/elegant solution, but I'll worry about that once it'll start to work as it should.

Comment: @ColeTierney - yes, this is original format.

Comment: @jhnc - mistake, got that when I removed unnecessary information; fixed that already, refresh the page and it should be good now.

Comment: Your script seems to work fine for me as written. I gave SOME_GHJ_REP_a as the sharename and it deleted the corresponding multipath block and the matching wwid line from the blacklist_exceptions block.

Comment: 1/2
@MarkReed - it would seem so, but create that file twice and see "diff" between them

If you run that normally, you'd get:
```
21a22
>         wwid "aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c5675"
53a55,58
>         }
>         multipath {
>         wwid    aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c5675
>         alias   SOME_GHJ_REP_lun.131
```

However if you add a number to every curly bracket that ends section, you'll get this:

Comment: 2/2 

```
21a22
>         wwid "aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c5675"
54a56,59
>         multipath {
>         wwid    aabbccddeeff00051752b4d32586c5675
>         alias   SOME_GHJ_REP_lun.131
>         }8
```


Either it looks okay because every section ends the same way and it's a coincidence or the diff output is buggy and everything's running fine and it's something completely different.

Comment: @0xBEE Are line numbers part of the source?

Comment: @ColeTierney - I'm afraid I don't quite understand. Could you clarify?

Comment: Start by fixing the issues with your script that http://shellcheck.net will tell you about so we can rule those out as the source of the problem.

Comment: @0xBEE Sed has a terse command set. If you don't like typing, it's a good thing ;) `q` is quit. The example I gave quits when the first non empty line is read. Sdtin is copied to sdtout. Add the `-n` if you're not iterested in the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
cat ur_file
1  "aa"
2  "bb"
3  "cc"
4  #
5  {
6  aa
7  name1
8  }
9  {
10 bb
11 name2
12 }
13 {
14 cc
15 name3
16 }
```

and

```
i=5
file="ur_file"
```

You can use GNU sed:

```
sed -i "$i"',+3d' "$file"  # -i is GNU only...
```

Or use awk:

```
awk -v i="$i" 'FNR<i || FNR>i+3' "$file" >"${file}.tmp" && mv -f "${file}.tmp" "$file"
```

Either one:

```
cat ur_file
1  "aa"
2  "bb"
3  "cc"
4  #
9  {
10 bb
11 name2
12 }
13 {
14 cc
15 name3
16 }
```

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't properly understood. I'm doing *two* sed deletion operations in a single script. First deletion works fine, the latter presents some issues.

Comment: I think you are misstating your problem. Why not just delete the entire block associated with `name1` in just one go rather than reading the file twice?

Comment: Because I'm deleting something related to that in the first portion of the file. I'll attach full function to the question, hopefully it'll make things clearer.

Comment: FWIW, `-i` is _not_ GNU only, but the suffix for the backup file - which is optional in GNU sed - is mandatory in BSD sed. So `sed -i -e` will create a backup file named 'filename.-e'.  If you add a value there (empty string means no backup file, e.g. `sed -i '' ...`) you get a command that works in both versions.